# Kafka producer can not connect to the kafka server on aws environment

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have kafka cluster deployed on EC2 instance, with ip `a.b.c.d` and dns name `XYZ_KAFKA`
the producer is also deployed on another EC2 instance with ip `a2.b2.c2.d2`, 
to connect to the kafka server the producer uses the dns name `XYZ_KAFKA`

on the producer log file it always give an error when try to produce

```
24 Oct 2017 07:01:35,384 INFO ProducerSendThread- kafka.producer.SyncProducer - Connected to XYZ_KAFKA:9092 for producing
24 Oct 2017 07:01:35,387 INFO ProducerSendThread- kafka.producer.SyncProducer - Disconnecting from XYZ_KAFKA:9092
codeVal 22
num of partitions 0
24 Oct 2017 07:01:35,388 ERROR ProducerSendThread- kafka.producer.SyncProducer - Producer connection to ip-a-b-c-d:9092 unsuccessful
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:107)
```

i updated `advertised.host.name=XYZ_KAFKA`, but still have the same error.
i am very confused how the producer cannot resolve the kafka dns name

one more point, i checked that the producer EC2 instance can see the kafka EC2 instance

```
nc -zv XYZ_KAFKA 9092
Connection to XYZ_KAFKA 9092 port [tcp/XmlIpcRegSvc] succeeded!
```

Comment: Kafka Broker Should be IPADDRESS:9092 . You are writing producer in java??

Comment: replace domain name  XYZ_KAFKA with IP address for advertised.host.name

Comment: @Nilesh, where to add IPADDRESS:9092 ?

Comment: @Nilesh, by replace domain name XYZ_KAFKA with IP you mean the kafka server IP or producer/consumer IP ?

Comment: Kafka server ip for advertised.host.name in config.